# Update edita todas as informações em vez de só uma especifica, quando coloco where para uma edição especifica nada é editado, o que fazer?

Tags: php, html, mysql

estou fazendo um código em que a pessoa adicione registros no site que são mostrados para ela em lista em uma table, em cada linha tem um botão para editar, quando faço a edição de alguma informação todos os outros registros são alterados, quando coloco um where no final do código de update e tento realizar alguma edição nada funciona e nenhuma informação é editada, alguém poderia me ajudar com isso? Já olhei o código todo e não consigo achar o problema.
Segue abaixo os 2 códigos:

Código para visualizar os registros e edita-los:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<!--Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Adicione uma pessoa para que possa ter o seu registro salvo</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--- Modal com form para se fazer a edição das informações -->
                <form class="form-group well" action="receberegistro.php?acao=alterar" method="POST">
                        <input type="hidden" name="codreg" value="<?php echo $codreg ?>">
                        <input type="text" name="nome" class="span3" value="
<?php echo $nome;?>" required placeholder="Nome" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="tel" name="tel" class="span3" placeholder="Número de telefone" required value="<?php echo $tel;?>" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="tel" name="cel" class="span3 pull-right" placeholder="Número de celular" required value="<?php echo $cel;?>" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="text" name="ende" class="span3" value="
<?php echo $ende;?>" required placeholder="Endereço" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Orçamento/Serviço" class="span3" required name="serv"><?php echo $serv;?></textarea><br><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" name="adicionar" style="height: 35px">Adicionar registro</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Teste</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<h2>Lista de pessoas registradas</h2><br>
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <input type="text" name="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar pessoas" class="span4" style="margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;">
        <button type="button" name="pesquisar" class="btn btn-large" style="height: 35px;">Pesquisar</button>
    </form>
    <table border="1px" bordercolor="gray" class="table table-stripped">
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>Telefone Fixo</td>
            <td>Celular</td>
            <td>Endereço</td>
            <td>Orçamento/Serviço</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Hora</td>
            <td>Ação</td>
        </tr>
            <?php   
                include_once('conectar.php');

                $consulta = mysql_query("select * from registro") or die (mysql_error());
                if(!empty($_POST['pesquisa']))
                {
                    $pesquisa = $_POST['pesquisa'];
                    $consulta = mysql_query("select * from registro '$pesquisa%'") or die(mysql_error());
                }
                while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($consulta))
                {
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dados['nome']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['tel']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['cel']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['ende']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['serv']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['data']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['hora']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="?acao=excluir&codreg=<?php echo $dados['codreg'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir este registro?');"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="excluir">Excluir</button></a>

                <a href="#myModal?acao=dados&codreg=<?php echo $dados['codreg'];?>"><button type="button" name="alterar" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Editar</button></a>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
<a href="registro.php"><button type="button" class="btn" name="voltar">Voltar</button></a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Código que recebe os registros, os mandam para o BD, altera, e etc:

```
<?php
$codreg = "";
$nome = "";
$tel = "";
$cel = "";
$ende = "";
$serv = "";
$data = "";
$hora = "";

if(!empty($_GET['acao']))
{
include_once("conectar.php");

$acao = $_GET['acao'];

if($acao == "cadastrar")
{
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $cel = $_POST['cel'];
    $ende = $_POST['ende'];
    $serv = $_POST['serv'];
    $data = date('d-m-y');
    $hora = date('h:i:s');

    $sql = mysql_query("insert into registro (nome, tel, cel, ende, serv, data, hora) values ('$nome','$tel','$cel','$ende','$serv','$data','$hora')") or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<script>alert('Dados cadastrados!'); window.location='registro.php';</script>";
}
else if($acao == "excluir")
{
    $codreg = $_GET['codreg'];
    $sql = mysql_query("delete from registro where codreg = '$codreg'") or die (mysql_error());
    header("location:consultaregistro.php");
}
else if($acao == "alterar")
{ 
    $codreg = $_POST'codreg'];
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $cel = $_POST['cel'];
    $ende = $_POST['ende'];
    $serv = $_POST['serv'];
    $data = date('d-m-y');
    $hora = date('h:i:s');

    $sql = mysql_query("update registro set 
        nome = '$nome',
        tel = '$tel',
        cel = '$cel',
        ende = '$ende',
        serv = '$serv' where codreg = '$codreg'") or die (mysql_error());

    echo "<script>alert('Dados gravados com sucesso!');window.location='consultaregistro.php';</script>";
}
else if($acao == "dados")
{
        //recebe o valor vindo do formulario
    $codreg = $_GET['codreg'];
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from registro where codreg ='$codreg'") or die (mysql_error());
    $dados = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    $nome = $dados['nome'];
    $tel = $dados['tel'];
    $cel = $dados['cel'];
    $ende = $dados['ende'];
    $serv = $dados['serv'];
    $data = date('d-m-y');
    $hora = date('h:i:s');

    //envia para o banco
    echo "<script>alert('Dados gravados com sucesso!');window.location='consultaregistro.php';</script>";
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Aconselho a [leres isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info)  teu código és vulnerável a vários tipos de ataques

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Corrige essa linha `$codreg = $_POST'codreg'];` no trecho abaixo para `$codreg = $_POST['codreg'];`

Falta o colchete `[` logo após `$_POST`

```
else if($acao == "alterar")
{ 
$codreg = $_POST'codreg'];
echo $codreg;
echo " alterar<br>";
```

**Mais um erro** - duas tags de fechamento `</a>`

`<a href="#myModal?acao=dados&codreg=<?php echo $dados['codreg'];?>"><button type="button" name="alterar" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Editar</button></a>
                </a>`

**Mais erro - o principal**

esse seu modal está cheio de echo, vou citar apenas um, o value desse input

`<input type="hidden" name="codreg" value="<?php echo $codreg ?>">`

e ao clicar em editar abre o modal com todos eles nulos.

**Mais erro** - esse link

`<a href="?acao=excluir&codreg=<?php echo $dados['codreg'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir este registro?');"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="excluir">Excluir</button></a>`

¿Não deveria apontar para `receberegistro.php` que é a pagina que recebe os registros, os mandam para o BD, altera, e etc ?

**Mais erro**  - No formulário de pesquisa o

`<button type="button" name="pesquisar"...` **tem que ser** `<button type="submit" name="pesquisar"...` que enviará o formulário.

`<button type="button" name="pesquisar"...` precisa de javascript para invocar o evento submit do form.

### Os erros são tantos que é melhor começar do zero

> E já que vamos começar do zero, é oportuno atualizar de mysql para mysqli, pois como todos sabemos mysql foi descontinuado. Saiba mais com [[[image]]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php/3869#3869)

**conectar.php**

```
$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario = "USUARIO";
$senha = "SENHA";
$dbname = "NOME_DB";

//Cria a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

if(!$conn){
    die("Falha na conexao: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

**Segue o código com os devidos comentários**

```
<?php
//declaração das variaveis
$codreg = "";
$nome = "";
$tel = "";
$cel = "";
$ende = "";
$serv = "";
$data = "";
$hora = "";

//conexão ao banco de dados
include_once('conectar.php');

if(!empty($_GET['acao'])){
   $acao = $_GET['acao'];

   if(($acao == "cadastrar")||($acao == "alterar")){
      $nome = $_POST['nome'];
      $tel = $_POST['tel'];
      $cel = $_POST['cel'];
      $ende = $_POST['ende'];
      $serv = $_POST['serv'];
      $data = date('d-m-y');
      $hora = date('h:i:s');
   }

   if($acao == "cadastrar"){
      $sql = ("insert into registro (nome, tel, cel, ende, serv, data, hora) values ('$nome','$tel','$cel','$ende','$serv','$data','$hora')");
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      //echo "<script>alert('Dados cadastrados!'); window.location='registro.php';</script>";
   }else if($acao == "excluir"){
      $codreg = $_GET['codreg'];
      $sql = ("delete from registro where codreg = '$codreg'");
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      //header("location:consultaregistro.php");
   }else if($acao == "alterar"){ 
      $codreg = $_POST['codreg'];
      $sql = ("update registro set nome = '$nome',tel = '$tel',cel = '$cel',ende = '$ende',serv = '$serv' where codreg = '$codreg'");
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      //echo "<script>alert('Dados alterados com sucesso!'); window.location='consultaregistro.php';</script>";
   }
}
?>
<!-- Biblioteca requerida -->
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>


<script>
/********************************************************************************
Função disparada ao clicar no link que abre o modal para edição (Modal Alterar)
valor é uma string com os dados cujo separador é um asteristico.
Com o metodo split separamos essa string para formar os valores a serem inseridos
nos campos do formulário do Modal Alterar
********************************************************************************/

function obterDadosModal(valor) {

   var retorno = valor.split("*");

   document.getElementById('campo').value = retorno[0];   
   document.getElementById('nome').value = retorno[1];    
   document.getElementById('tel').value = retorno[2];
   document.getElementById('cel').value = retorno[3];  
   document.getElementById('ende').value = retorno[4]; 
   document.getElementById('serv').value = retorno[5]; 
}
</script>



<div class="container">
<!--Modal Cadastrar-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalCadastrar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Adicione uma pessoa para que possa ter o seu registro salvo</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--- Modal com form para se fazer inclusão de registro -->
                <form class="form-group well" action="receberegistro.php?acao=cadastrar" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="nome" class="span3" value="" required placeholder="Nome" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="tel" name="tel" class="span3" placeholder="Número de telefone" required value="" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="tel" name="cel" class="span3 pull-right" placeholder="Número de celular" required value="" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input type="text" name="ende" class="span3" value="" required placeholder="Endereço" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Orçamento/Serviço" class="span3" required name="serv"></textarea><br><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" name="adicionar" style="height: 35px">Adicionar registro</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Teste</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="container">
<!--Modal Alterar-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalAlterar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">

        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1>Alteração de Registro</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!--- Modal com form para se fazer a edição das informações -->
                <form class="form-group well" action="receberegistro.php?acao=alterar" method="POST">
                        <input id="campo" type="text" id="codreg" name="codreg" value="">
                        <input id="nome" type="text" name="nome" class="span3" value="" required placeholder="Nome" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input id="tel" type="tel" name="tel" class="span3" placeholder="Número de telefone" required value="" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input id="cel" type="tel" name="cel" class="span3 pull-right" placeholder="Número de celular" required value="" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <input id="ende" type="text" name="ende" class="span3" value="" required placeholder="Endereço" style=" margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;"><br><br>
                        <textarea id="serv" placeholder="Orçamento/Serviço" class="span3" required name="serv"></textarea><br><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" name="editar" style="height: 35px">Alterar registro</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Teste</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
<h2>Lista de pessoas registradas</h2><br>
    <form method="POST" action="receberegistro.php?acao=dados">
        <input type="text" name="pesquisa" placeholder="Pesquisar pessoas" class="span4" style="margin-bottom: -2px; height: 25px;">
        <button type="submit" name="pesquisar" class="btn btn-large" style="height: 35px;">Pesquisar</button> 
        <a href="#myModalCadastrar"><button type="button" name="cadastrar" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalCadastrar">Cadastrar</button></a>
    </form>
    <table border="1px" bordercolor="gray" class="table table-stripped">
        <tr>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>Telefone Fixo</td>
            <td>Celular</td>
            <td>Endereço</td>
            <td>Orçamento/Serviço</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Hora</td>
            <td>Ação</td>
        </tr>
            <?php

                $consulta = ("select * from registro");

                if(!empty($_POST['pesquisa']))
                {
                    $pesquisa = $_POST['pesquisa'];
                    $consulta = ("select * from registro where nome like '$pesquisa%'");
                }

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $consulta);

                while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $dados['nome']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['tel']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['cel']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['ende']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['serv']?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['data']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $dados['hora']; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="receberegistro.php?acao=excluir&codreg=<?php echo $dados['codreg'];?>" onclick="return confirm('Deseja realmente excluir este registro?');"><button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="excluir">Excluir</button></a>
                //aqui aproveitamos os dados da consulta acima para servirem de parametros na função obterDadosModal e serem utilizados no ModalAlterar
                <a href="#myModalAlterar" onclick="obterDadosModal('<?php echo $dados['codreg'];?>*<?php echo $dados['nome'];?>*<?php echo $dados['tel'];?>*<?php echo $dados['cel'];?>*<?php echo $dados['ende'];?>*<?php echo $dados['serv'];?>')"><button type="button" id='alterar' name='alterar' class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalAlterar">Editar</button></a>

            </td>
        </tr>
            <?php
                }
                mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
    </table>
</div>
<a href="registro.php"><button type="button" class="btn" name="voltar">Voltar</button></a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Não funcionou, o erro persiste

Comment: @LuizOleia, pois é, o erro não é só a falta de colchete em $codreg = $_POST'codreg']; São inúmeros os erros como você pode ver na resposta editada. Enfim são tantos que achei melhor criar do zero.

Answer (score -1):

Simples, você esta enviando pelo metodo POST, e esta tentando pegar essa informação pelo GET por isso não esta dando certo o UPDATE.

Como esta:

```
$codreg = $_GET['codreg'];
```

Como deve ficar:

```
 $codreg = $_POST['codreg'];
```

e mantenha a condição (WHERE).

Comment: Não é isso, já tentei fazer isso antes, mudei agora denovo, e ainda assim não funciona

Comment: Na tela do formulário aonde você pega o id (codreg ) para enviar, nesta parte?
 <input type="hidden" name="codreg" value="<?php echo $codreg ?>">

Comment: Sim, e antes disso estava tentando puxar o id para  a variavel $codreg por select, mas ambos não funcionaram

Comment: Poderia posta o codigo utilizado para puxar o ID

Comment: Antes eu estava tentando fazer assim:

Linhas de php no codigo de consultaI (o que tem os botões de editar) antes de começar o código html:
<?php

    include_once("receberegistro.php");
 $acao = "?acao=cadastrar"; //não muda
    if(!empty($_GET['codreg'])) //muda de acordo com o nome do código da tabela
    {
 $acao = "?acao=alterar&codreg=$codreg";//muda de acordo com o campo
    } 
    ?>

Comment: No form para a edição das informações esta assim:

    <form class="form-group well" action="<?php echo $acao; ?>" method="POST">

Comment: E no arquivo que altera assim:

    else if($acao == "alterar")
 { 
  $codreg = $_GET['codreg'];
  $nome = $_POST['nome'];
  $tel = $_POST['tel'];
  $cel = $_POST['cel'];
  $ende = $_POST['ende'];
  $serv = $_POST['serv'];
  $data = date('d-m-y');
  $hora = date('h:i:s');

  $sql = mysql_query("update registro set 
   nome = '$nome',
   tel = '$tel',
   cel = '$cel',
   ende = '$ende',
   serv = '$serv' where codreg = '$codreg'") or die (mysql_error());

  echo "<script>alert('Dados gravados com sucesso!');window.location='consultaregistro.php';</script>";
 }